# Using || for multiple strings in an if statement in swift

Tags: string, swift, foundation, command-line-tool

I'm making a command line Swift app and I have a user prompt where users can answer "yes" and proceed or anything else and exit. But I was thinking what if someone answers "y" or "YES" or "Yes" or "yEs". I've tried using || but apparently that is only for ints.

This is my code:

```
var askNewFile = getInput()
    if askNewFile == ("yes") {
        //code to start blank editor
    }
    else {
        print("Bye!")
        exit(1)
    }
```

I would appreciate any help, or even nudges in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all the words that mean "yes" into an array and do a case-insensitive search on the user's input:

```
let isYes =  ["y", "yes", "yeah", "yup"].contains {
    askNewFile.compare($0, options: [.CaseInsensitiveSearch]) == .OrderedSame
}
if isYes {
    // User answered yes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you wanted to be able to use the OR conditional with String only values you could try the following formula

```
let animal = "Fox"
if animal == "Cat" || animal == "Dog" {
print("Animal is a house pet.")
} else {
print("Animal is not a house pet.")
}
```

You need to remember to put the originating value and  ==  before each new String value you want to test, in this case:  ' animal '